# read from socket part of data but only once

Tags: sockets

I would like to get data from serial port on uClinux. How it works: I have peripheral device that I want to enter bootloader mode. To do this I have to send data i2500$ and it means that it is in bootloader mode. Unfortunetly I can read only >i2 and if I use my method it do not return data any more or if i reset the device and repeat start jumping to bootloader by

```
int TEnforaUpdate::ReadFromComport (unsigned long timeouta, unsigned long size)
{
  FD_SET(fdCom, &read_fds);
  int retValue = 0;
  // Set timeout to x microseconds
  struct timeval timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = 0;
  timeout.tv_usec = 1000 * timeouta;
  // Wait for input to become ready or until the time out; the first parameter is
  // 1 more than the largest file descriptor in any of the sets
  if ((select (fdCom + 1, &read_fds, &write_fds, &except_fds, &timeout) == 1)
      && (FD_ISSET(fdCom,&read_fds)))
  {
    //read max
    retValue = read (fdCom, RxBuffer, RX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    printf ("Read %d bytes: ", retValue);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < retValue; i++)
      printf ("[%02x]", RxBuffer[i]);
    printf ("\n");   
  }
  else
    return 1;
  if (retValue > 2)
  {
    strcpy (answer, (char*) RxBuffer);
    //remove trashes from buffer
    memset (RxBuffer, 0x00, RX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    printf ("Comport answers: %s \n", answer);
  }
  FD_CLR(fdCom, &read_fds);
  tcflush (fdCom, TCIFLUSH);
  return retValue;
}
```

Comment: `I can read only >i2` what does that mean?

Comment: i can read from serial port only part of response >i2 but full of response is >i2500$ and it is(i verify it by logic analyser).

Comment: You are assuming that read reads the whole message at once. Read can read any amount including just once byte.

Comment: I know, I can define it by RX_BUFFER_SIZE=256 but still after reading data I can not read the rest of the data. For example if I call ReadFromComport (here it reads data) and wait 5ms and again ReadFromComport (here it do not read data). It not reads rest of the data after 5ms. I will explain in different way if my function can read only beginning of data how can I read the rest? I need polling mechanism or something like this. Someone on other forum sugest that it might be connected with blocking and nonblocking function

Comment: Are you using non-blocking sockets? Either use blocking IO or asynchronous IO (epoll). That way you don't need polling at all. Non-blocking sockets are usually not a good idea.